# Flight connections in JFK

Tags: usa, transit, jfk, lebanese-citizens

I have read on other questions, that you can get vouchers in JFK to make the immigration process easier and quicker.
I come from a Lebanon which I think is more suspicious then others.  My first layover is in London for 2 hours, then my second on is in JFK for 2:50 hours before going to Nashville.

I'm just going there to see a friend so I travel on a Lebanese Passport with US Tourist Visa.

- Will 2:50 hours be enough? I have to transfer from terminal 7 to terminal 8.
  ( Going with the British airways).
- I am extremely stressing about this, because I have already completely booked my flight, and the travel agent didn't tell me anything about this, not until I started looking things up.
  Will things be ok?
- Plus, do you think it's possible to ask the airways to get my bags to arrive on the very final destination? And not to JFK?

Comment: You may find at least partial answers to your questions here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/transit-in-us-airport

Comment: Welcome to travel.se.  First off there are too many questions in your question and it may need to be split up.  Having said that.  What immigration vouchers are you talking about?  *Will things be ok?* what things? And if you are looking for reassurance this is unfortunately the wrong forum for this as we are about information.

Comment: Another related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/what-is-the-connecting-time-to-consider-for-international-to-international-trans

Comment: One additional related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/956/what-is-the-minimum-time-to-consider-with-a-connecting-flight-in-the-usa?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

2 hours 50 minutes is plenty of time under normal conditions.  As the numbers imply, terminals 7 and 8 are side-by-side, and catching the airtrain between terminals is (relatively) quick and easy.

Presuming you have booked both flights on a single ticket, if there are any problems that cause you to miss your connecting flight (flight delays, hold-ups in immigration, etc) then the airline will move you to a later flight at no charge.

Due to immigration and customs, all flights into the US require you to collect your bags at your first point of entry into the US. Thus in JFK you will need to collect your bags and take them though customs with you.  Once through customs, if your bag has been tagged all the way to your destination (which it likely will have), you can simply drop it at the baggage drop point, and then make your way to terminal 8.  If your bag has not been tagged all the way through to Nashville then you will need to take it to terminal 8 yourself.